# How can I send a new prop to a component after time using the setTimeout() function?

Tags: reactjs, settimeout, flash-message

I have a component called **flash** that is intended to be in the DOM only for 5 seconds (it's a message informing the user that he has sent the post successfully) and I want it to start fading away after 2 seconds, so that after 5 seconds when it's removed from the DOM it already has visibility set to 0.
To achieve this, in the parent component I setTimeout() and send a prop containing a boolean set to true to the **flash** component, where it has an if waiting for that boolean and when it gets it, it assigns a new class to that component to make it fade away. It all sounds perfect, but unfortunately it doesn't work at all... I tried updating the class within the **flash** component but it also doesn't work... Maybe you can come up with something? I'm sure that sending flash messages in react with pre-arranged components is a trifle in React, but I just can't think of any way of doing it!

Parent component:

````
        if(this.state.flashMessage){
            flash = <Flash>{this.state.flashMessage}</Flash>
            setTimeout(() => {
                //here I send the component the prop 'close' after two seconds
                flash = <Flash close>{this.state.flashMessage}</Flash>
            }, 2000);
        }

        return ( 
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className={classes.postContainer}>
                    {posts}
                    <div className={classes.Card} onClick={this.showPostAdd}>
                        <img alt="add a post" src={addPostImage} />
                    </div>
                </div> 
                {addPostActive}
                {flash}                    
            </React.Fragment>               
        );```

Here is the flash component

``` const flash = (props) => {
    let classNames = [classes.Flash];

    if(props.close){
        classNames.push(classes.TestFlash);
    }
    
    return (
        <div className={classNames.join(' ')}>
            <p>{props.children}</p>
        </div>
    );
}
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The render only runs when updating the component, and a setTimeout won't trigger that update. However, changing a state value does trigger the update for the component.

What you should do is print the Flash component directly on the *render* method and bind the ***close*** prop to a state boolean.

```
<Flash close={this.state.closeFlashMessage}>{this.state.flashMessage}</Flash>
```

And I'd put the timeout function on the ***componentDidMount()*** method.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.mounted = true;

    setTimeout(() => {
        //check the mounted state in case the component is disposed before the timeout.
        if(this.mounted) {
            //here I send the component the prop 'close' after two seconds
            this.setState({ closeFlashMessage: true });
        }                
    }, 2000);
}

//add this method to prevent any state management during the component's disposal
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.mounted = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked well for me!

Answer (score 1):

This does not work because simply setting `flash = ...` will not trigger a re-render. You will need to store that information in your component's state and update it there in order to make it work correctly. I think something like this would work:

```
{this.state.flashMessage && <Flash close={this.state.isFlashMessageClosed}>{this.state.flashMessage}</Flash>
```

I would also not recommend setting a timeout directly in your render method. This should be a side effect triggered by a state change so I would recommend putting it in `componentDidUpdate` like so:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if(prevState.flashMessage !== this.state.flashMessage) { 
    // If the flash message changed, update state to show the message
    this.setState({ isFlashMessageClosed: false });

    setTimeout(()=>{
      // Update state to close the message after 2 seconds
      this.setState({ isFlashMessageClosed: true });
    }, 2000);
  }
}
```

Hopefully that will work for you.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked well for me!